# Hystrix threadpool maximumSize, coreSize and allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize not working?

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, hystrix, netflix-archaius

I've set hystrix threadpool configuration as - `coreSize=10`, `maximumSize=100` and `allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize=true` for the command key. I deployed the application but it's rejecting the threads when QPS is high -

```
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.RejectedExecutionException: Task java.util.concurrent.FutureTask@7bb2e868 rejected from java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor@39627710[Running, pool size = 10, active threads = 10, queued tasks = 0, completed tasks = 3409]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$AbortPolicy.rejectedExecution(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:2047)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.reject(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:823)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.execute(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1369)
    at java.util.concurrent.AbstractExecutorService.submit(AbstractExecutorService.java:112)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextScheduler$ThreadPoolWorker.schedule(HystrixContextScheduler.java:172)
    at com.netflix.hystrix.strategy.concurrency.HystrixContextScheduler$HystrixContextSchedulerWorker.schedule(HystrixContextScheduler.java:106)
```

I'm using `hystrix-javanica 1.5.12` version. This is not working as queued tasks are 0.

The rest of the default values are as follows (names below are abstracted a bit) -

```
    isCircuitBreakerEnabled = true;
    circuitBreakerRequestVolumeThreshold = 10;
    isFallBackEnabled = false;
    circuitBreakerSleepWindow = 10000;
    circuitBreakerErrorThresholdPercentage = 50;
    circuitBreakerForceOpen = false;
    circuitBreakerForceClosed = false;
    metricsRollingStats = 10000;
    executionIsolationThreadTimeOut = 20000;
    executionIsolationStrategy = "THREAD";
    executionTimeOutEnable = true;
    poolCoreSize = 10;
    poolMaxSize = 15;
    poolMaxQueueSize = -1;
    keepAliveTime = 1;
    poolQueueSizeRejectionThreshold = 1;
    allowMaximumSizeToDivergeFromCoreSize = false;
```

I was following the issue - https://github.com/Netflix/Hystrix/issues/1436. One more person reported the similar issue with this version in 2017.

Do you think I'm missing any configuration? Should I change executionIsolationStrategy to `Semaphore` to make it work?

Comment: I tried debugging it into hystrix libraries. Seems like we have some issues with Archaius way of setup and javanica way of using aspect.